# Justification of the tangent name for the goniometric operator $\tan$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definition

When we give a proof that the tangent is the sine to cosine ratio of an oriented angle,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\tan \alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos \alpha}}$$
with $\cos \alpha \neq 0$, we take the tangent $t$ in $A(1,0)\equiv S$ to the circle of center in $O(0,0)$ ad radius $r=1$. See the image

[image: https://www.youmath.it/images/stories/funzioni-elementari/definizione-tangente.png]

> The name tangent has been given because we consider the tangent to the circle of radius $1$ at point $A\equiv S$ or for another reason?

Comment: Yes, "tangent" takes its name from its association with a *tangent* line of the unit circle. Likewise, "secant" is named for a *secant* line. And "sine" for (a mistranslation of) *semi-chord*. ... Curiously, according to the [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words in Mathematics site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html), "Vieta did not approve of the term *tangent* because it could be confused with the term in geometry." The connection with geometry is, to me, a feature of the terminology.

Comment: @Blue Can you convert your comment into an answer please? The history it is very nice :-) "Vieta did not approve of tangent because it could be confused with the term in geometry"

Comment: @downvoter: What is the reason to get an downvote for my question? Please, explain me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good reason and it is consistent also with the other equivalent definition for the tangent

[image]

([credit](http://advancedmathyoungstudents.com/blog/2014/12/19/trig-pictures-part-iii/))

Refer also to [The Etymology of Trig Functions](https://mathisonian.github.io/trig/etymology/#:%7E:text=Tangent%20comes%20from%20the%20latin,verb%20meaning%20%22to%20touch%22.&text=It%20comes%20from%20the%20latin,the%20circle%20in%20two%20pieces.).

Comment: Can I ask you a kindness if I could personalize the drawing with comments, according to my question, because when I show the cotangent I take the tangent to the circle at the point $(0,1)$ regarding the tangent line. Please can you extend your answer? Thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: @Sebastiano My intention was to show that also the other equivalent definition for the tangent is also related to a tangent line. I'm not sure which one has determined the name or both of them. In any case it seems very likely that the name has that fact as origin.

Comment: @Sebastiano What do you mean with "personalize the drawing with comments"? SOrry I don't get your point.

Comment: In the meantime, I voted for more of your beautiful answers. I don't often look at the comments and am happy to assign the votes.

Comment: Why $|AB|=\cot \alpha$? and $|BE|=\tan \alpha$? :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano By similarity $BE/BC=BD/DC$ :)

Comment: I am sleeping :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I also was introduced with the one you presented but this also an interesting equivalent one! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "tangent" takes its name from its association with a *tangent* line of the unit circle. Likewise, "secant" is named for a *secant* line. And "sine" for (a mistranslation of) semi-chord.

Curiously, according to the [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words in Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html) site (which has entries for all of the terms), "Vieta did not approve of the term tangent because it could be confused with the term in geometry." To me, the connection with geometry is a *feature* of the terminology.

FYI: The geometry is a focus of my note ["(Almost) Everything You Need to Remember about Trigonometry, in One Simple Diagram (PDF link via tricochet.com)"](http://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/AlmostEverythingAboutTrig.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious effort.....and to have convert the comment like an answer.

Comment: I'll note my ["Fundamental Trigonograph" poster on Etsy](https://etsy.com/listing/788311128). (If there is objection to such self-promotion, I'll delete this comment.)

Comment: @Blue Thanks for your note!

Comment: In Math.SE. very little is said about the history of mathematics and curiosity :-). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Many history-related questions have been redirected to the relatively-new dedicated ["History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange"](http://hsm.stackexchange.com). (Arguably, your question might get more-detailed responses there.)

Comment: Thank you very much...and thank you again for your beautiful answer.